# How to disable Wordpress blog folder

Tags: posts, api, blog, json

I've integrated Wordpress into my existing website and used [WP JSON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) to get the content from WordPress, but I don't want the WordPress itself to be available to my viewers.

When I refresh my website (`myWebsite.com/blog`), it appends a slash (`/`) and goes to `myWebsite.com/blog/`, which goes to the WordPress website itself and does not show mine.

How can I make sure that it does not append a slash to the URL and does not go to the WordPress theme when I refresh the page?

Comment: You might be able to `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);` - https://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website then remove the WP specific items in your `.htaccess` that do redirects

Comment: @user3226932 Are you still experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, `/blog` and `/blog/` are the same. The slash is added by the browser to properly structure the URL (best way I can explain it).

Your're trying to access two different pages with the `/blog/` slug. In this case, WordPress is overriding the blog link from your existing website and showing content from there.

What you'll need to do is set your WordPress site to a different location other than `/blog/`, such as:

`myWebsite.com/wordpress/`

Then, you will want to prevent unauthorized access to your WordPress site if someone got ahold of the link. You can use a simple plugin such as [Force Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-login/) which require visitors to log in order to interact with the website.